# homogeneous coordinates of projective scheme

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

Suppose $R$ is a ring, $P^n_R$ - projective scheme. If $k$ is a field, there is a one to one correspondence between $k$-rational points of $P_k^n$ and $P^n$, given by homogeneous coordinates $[X_0:...:X_n]$. How do homogeneous coordinates work in case of $ProjR[X_0,...,X_n]$, when $R$ is not a field?
Is there a good reference about this? I can't seem to find anything explicitly stated anywhere.

Comment: Try asking youself another question: Are there coordinates on $\mathrm{Spec} R$ where $R$ is any ring? Then note that $\mathrm{Proj}R[X_0,\ldots,X_N]=\mathrm{Spec} R \times \mathbb Z[X_0,\ldots,X_N]$.

Comment: Dear @Frederik, there is a typo in your equality.

Comment: @FredrikMeyer Well, I understood by now, that on one hand these coordinates are the glueing data to pass to grassmanians on one hand and on the other, well defined sections of first twisting sheaf of Serre, but seems still a bit hazy, since the coordinates are not exactly elements of R, are they?